# Run a java module from Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

I added a java module to my project and tried to run it with a configuration. I choosed the main class. When I try to run, I get this exception;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Main
```

I also have installed IntellijIDEA 12 community edition, there is no problem running a java module with this installation.

So what should I do to run java module from Android Studio?

Note: I want to do this because my project is a client-server application. I want to handle them both with same IDE. I use Android for client and Java for server.

Comment: Check your classpath environment variable..

Comment: I read about classpath but it is under project structure and Android Studio currently has no UI for this. Can you tell where should I look for this?

Comment: [Set the CLASSPATH environment variable](http://www.ecs.umass.edu/ece/ece122/help/setenvironment.htm)

Comment: I checked classpath, values are right. And like I mentioned in the question, community version runs without problem, so I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: I am not use to `IntellijIDEA`. But in eclipse in your project have you added `JRE System Library` ie your IDE build path.

Comment: Since [Java Module](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html) is a thing now, did you meant android module?

Answer (score -1):

To run a Java module from Android Studio, you can create a new Java module in your Android Studio project and then run it as you would run any other Java application. Here's a general outline of the steps:

**Create a Java module:**

Go to File > New > New Module.
Select "Java Library" and click Next.
Enter the module name and other details, and click Finish.
Write your Java code:

Write your Java code in the newly created module.
Configure the run configuration:

Go to Run > Edit Configurations.
Click the "+" icon and select "Application".
In the "Main class" field, enter the fully qualified name of the class containing the main method.
Run the module:

Click the Run button or press Shift+F10 to run the Java module.